# Was the siege on for a whole day or over several days?

Tags: plot-explanation, white-house-down

In ***White House Down*** the siege looks like it hasn't had a  single night in it.
Was it going for a whole day or was there night in the movie too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-watched the movie and there is no indication at any point that there is any action taking place at night.

Indeed, the whole movie seems to take place in the hours of daylight **in a single day**. te movie starts in the daylight / morning and ends with the helicopter flight *apparently* before nightfall the same day.

There are no onscreen times but clocks & watches in the movie are few and far between (and subject to continuity errors) but there are a few specifically that I noticed.

- Kale interviews for Secret Service - 9:00am [Clock on wall]
- Kale is outside the White House trying to abort the airstrike : 6:30 pm (presumably) [wristwatch]
- Final shootout in Oval Office: approx 7:00pm [this one is a little vague as it's a grandfather-clock with ornate hands]

Comment: so you are saying they were on daylight savings time?